# Get Current Selected Variation ID and Name in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I have a problem and no ideia how to resolve, basically I need the attribute name and value after the user selected.

**To be simple I trying to put the attributes name and ID in a PHP variable because I need to use that.**

I tried this:

```
$product_id = $product->get_id();

$product = wc_get_product($product_id);


if ($product) {
    
    $attribute = $product->get_attribute('tamanhos');
    echo '<p>'.$attribute.'</p>';
} else {
    // the case when the product does not exist
}
```

This code only show all the attributes options I have, but I need the attribute that user was selected and put the data in a php var.

Someone know how can I do that?

Comment: For info, in your actual code, you get already the WC_Product object `$product`from the start, so **you don't need (just remove):** `$product_id = $product->get_id();` and `$product = wc_get_product($product_id);`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the selected variation and pass some data to PHP, as this is a client side event, it can not be done via PHP directly, but it requires using JavaScript (jQuery).

Here is an example usage based on your code, to get and display the selected variation ID, name and the value for the product attribute "tamanhos" *(also, adding to a hidden input field "tamanhos" value)*:

```php
// Add some extra variation data to the variable product form
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'add_product_variation_tamanhos_attr', 10, 3);
function add_product_variation_tamanhos_attr( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    // Set the "tamanhos" attribute value to variable product form for this variation
    if( $tamanhos = $variation->get_attribute('tamanhos') ) {
        $variation_data['tamanhos'] = $tamanhos;
    }
    // Variation name
    $variation_data['name'] = $variation->get_name();

    return $variation_data;
}

// Add a custom hidden input field
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_variation','custom_variable_product_hidden_input_field', 30 );
function custom_variable_product_hidden_input_field(){
    echo '<div class="custom-hidden-fields">
    <input type="hidden" name="tamanhos" value="" />
    </div>';
}

// JQuery code
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form', 'display_product_variation_tamanhos_attr_js' );
function display_product_variation_tamanhos_attr_js() {
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function(event, data) {
            const variationID   = data.variation_id, 
                  variationName = data.name,
                  tamanhosAttr  = data.tamanhos,
                  htmlOutput    = '<div style="border:solid 1px red;padding:2px 8px" class="custom-data">Variation ID: ' +
                  variationID + ' | Name: ' + variationName + ' | Tamanhos: ' + tamanhosAttr + '</div>';

            // Display the selected variation ID, name and "Tamanhos" attribute value
            $('.woocommerce-variation-price').after(htmlOutput);

            // Set "Tamanhos" attribute value in a hidden input field
            $('input[name=tamanhos]').val(tamanhosAttr);

            // Display the data in the javascript console
            console.log('Variation ID: ' + variationID + ' | Name: ' + variationName  + ' | Tamanhos: '+ tamanhosAttr); 
        }).on('hide_variation', function(){
            $('.custom-data').remove(); // Remove displayed data
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

**Note:** By default, there is already a hidden input field where the selected variation ID is displayed.

> Now to pass that values to PHP it can be done via:
>
> - Some hidden fields added to the variation form, where you will set the selected variation values using jQuery. Then on add to cart, those hidden field values will be posted,
> - AJax (and may be WooCommerce session variables).